# Setting a number between tags as a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a number (`x`) inside tags, ie: `<span id="Number">x</span>` and set that as a variable.

Am I even on the right track with this? Not even close?

```
var y = $('#Number').nextUntil('span');
```

Comment: could you post some more code or elaborate more on the question. I am not quite sure what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

If you want the content of the span, do this:

```
var y = $('#Number').text();
```

You need to think of them as whole elements, not individual opening/closing tags. The [`text()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method gives you the text content of the `span` element you selected by ID.

The code above will give you a String. If you want a Number, you can convert it like this:

```
var y = parseInt( $('#Number').text(), 10);
```

or this:

```
var y = +$('#Number').text();
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.  What is the 10 for btw?

Comment: @Dim Panda: You're welcome. The second argument sets the radix so you can ensure base 10 conversion. If your `x` number happened to be 015 for example, it would be parsed as an octal if the radix isn't explicitly set.